# Glass GDK: any function that writes, doesn't write

Tags: java, android, google-glass, google-gdk

Any function that reads from storage works fine.

Instances of different functions that write something - eg changing file path of camera intent, writing to an XML file - all fail. Gracefully - they just haven't actually written anything.

We have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

What are we missing?

Code if needed, but this happens on XML file (append with DOM Parser) as well as images being saved (attempted to be..) other than through camera's default method - so I suspect it's something general.

Thanks.

Comment: So your pictures are being saved but you are trying to append them to your current view in glass? 
I am a little confused about your question. Also posting what you have so far might help.

Comment: No we can take and read pictures fine. But if we try to 'manually' save anything, like change camera save path, or edit an XML file, there's no errors but it doesn't write out.

Comment: Please provide code (snippets at least) and manifest

Comment: It turned out to be a bug in GDK. Reported, and presumably now fixed. Unfortunate timing for the hackathon though. Should I close this question? I can't see it's of use to anyone else now.